# Get ReleaseNotes from nuget feed programatically when possible

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

Some packages like [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp/0.15.0) have 'Release Notes' in their nuget feed.

[IPackageMetadata.cs](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/PackageCreation/Authoring/IPackageMetadata.cs) have `ReleaseNotes` but it seems this is only used when creating a package.

Is there a way to get `ReleaseNotes` when possible?

PS: there is an example for [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk#get-package-metadata), but there is nothing useful there.